# How do i set ms access 2007 database in crystal report

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports

I am trying to design a report in crystal report.

I have ms access 2007 as my database.

I started with new blank report file in crystal report. I thought creating new database connection using oledb but can find options for mdb files only but not the accdb file.

how can i get connected crystal report with access 2007 db

**Edit:**

I created new report.
1.) Clicked on **Database Expert**
2.) Clicked on **Create New Connection**
3.) Dbl Clicked on **OLE DB (ADO)**
4.) Choosed **Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLEDB Provider**
5.) **Manually Copied .accdb file path** from windows explorer and **pasted** it on **Data Source**
6.) Clicked on **Next** and **Finish**.

And finally it worked...

Is that fine? instead of copying file path manually isn't there a way to specify the path with browse functionality as in others?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are a bunch of database access DLLs that you can choose to install when you install crystal, you may want to check that you have the correct database access files installed.
2. It maybe depreciated by MS but I find using the ODBC drivers works better with older file types. (I'm sure some one will tell me off for recommending this, but I guessing its not a mission critical report you are looking at)

Cheers
B

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard method for linking to Access databases: **Database Expert->Create New Connection->Access/Excel (DAO)**

Have you already tried this method?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate Jet/ACE installed on the machine with Crystal?

Comment: I think I understand now.  Can you convert your .accdb to .mdb? In Access 2003, those options are under **tools->database utilities->convert database->to Access 2003 format**. The downside is that you may lose some functionality with the database, but Crystal probably doesn't use that functionality anyway.

Comment: hm.. well that conversion worked for me. But can we also do it without converting or not? I tried one way as mentioned in above question edited section. Is that also fine?

Comment: (To be honest, I only have Access 2003, not 2007, so I'm making some guesses here).  I think your method would work fine, but to be safe, you could run some test reports and compare them against some independently calculated results.

Answer (score -3):

done that been there. It is getting harder with 2007 especially with Chrystal reports.
1)
 Make a shell msaccess app tthat links to be databases
 look into the north wind database same and figure out how to relink databases

In Chrystal reports use ODBC to link to the shell database.

Chrystal reports is getting difficult to use as it no longer supports Active X instead it use .net. I did get it work with Msaccess 2007-2010. but have issues with Access 
2013